# Virtual key pad issue

Tags: android

I have an edittext view with a default text value like 'Enter Value'. When the user touches the edittext I want to clear the edittext value and show the virtual keypad to the user.

I did this it is still not working. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        edtsearch.setText("");
        //((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(edtsearch, 0);  
        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.showSoftInput(edtsearch, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

        return true;
    }
```

The above code didn't show keypad. Can anybody tell me how to clear the value and show keypad to the user?

Even I used android:hint at the time of keypad clicking only it clear the value. I want if user touch the edit text box clear the value and show keypad to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which you are expecting is the default behaviour of Android `EditText`.

You dont have any thing to do

1. Just remove `onTouch` method from your code
2. Keep the `hint`.

Thats all you  need.

Comment: @mohan This is the documentation for the [hint attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint)